# CloudKit: 'fetchRecordsCompletionBlock' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use fetchRecordsResultBlock instead?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, ckrecord

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/olmps/NestedCloudKitCodable) to encode and decode custom structs using `CloudKit` however, ran into this depreciation and the library hasn't been updated.  How can I rewrite this block below?

```
   private func fetchAllAssociatedRecords(fromReferences references: [CKRecord.Reference],
                                           recordsStack records: [CKRecord],
                                           referenceDatabase database: CKDatabase,
                                           completion: @escaping ([CKRecord]?, CKCodableError?) -> Void) {
        let query = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: references.map { $0.recordID })
  //problem line --> query.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { (recordsDictionary, error) in
            if let receivedError = error {
                let error = CKCodableError.error(fromCloudkitError: receivedError)
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            if let fetchedRecordsDictionary = recordsDictionary {
                let fetchedRecords = fetchedRecordsDictionary.map { $0.value }
                self.fetchReferences(fromRecords: fetchedRecords,
                                     andAppendTo: records,
                                     withReferenceDatabase: database,
                                     completion: completion)

            } else {
                let error = CKCodableError(.cloudkitInconsistence)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
        database.add(query)
    }
```

Comment: Deprecated means it works at least until the next major upgrade (iOS 16). How about asking the developer for an update (file an issue). The future is the async/await API anyway.

Comment: Or, even better, fork the framework, update the code and submit a PR.  Also, consider whether you even want to make this change; `fetchRecordsResultBlock` is iOS15+ only, so you will either need to handle both cases using `if available` or target IOS15 only or ignore the deprecation warning